# Sencha extjs disable year in datepicker with monthfield

Tags: javascript, extjs

my item :

```js
xtype: 'monthfield',
reference: 'debutmonth',
emptyText: 'date',
format: 'F, Y'
```

when i use

```js
disabledYears: ['../2021']
```

the year is always selectable

Comment: Official documentation has no mention about property `disabledYears`. What version of extjs you use? Maybe for this property has a some method that processes it? Please give more information. If it possible - make an example in the fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
sorry i mean disabledDates [https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html#method-setDisabledDates]
the version of sencha is **6.5.1**
and i want to deactivate the click on years not just on days 
my item : 
`{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    reference: 'date',
    format: 'F, Y',
}`

Comment: You needed on disabled of all years starting with some year (period) or it should be certain years (exactly like `disabledDays`)?

Comment: i need to disable a period like **from 2016 to 2019**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ext.picker.Date to set the years disabled. The years can be selectable in the picker dropdown but the dates will be disabled for the entire year(s).

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 300,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            title: 'Dates',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'datefield',
                anchor: '100%',
                fieldLabel: 'From',
                name: 'from_date',
                listeners:{
                    afterrender: function(datefield){
                        var datePicker = datefield.getPicker();
                        datePicker.setDisabledDates(['../../2016','../../2017','../../2018','../../2019']);
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```